# Does the number of right chiral neutrinos always need to be the same as the number of anti left chiral neutrinos?

Tags: antimatter, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model, chirality

Neutrinos are only observed to have a left handed chirality and anti neutrinos are only observed as having a right chirality. In some beyond the standard model hypotheses neutrinos of right chirality are modeled as being much bigger than left chiral neutrinos with a potential mass as large as $10^{15}$ GeV, if these even exist would there be some rule that says there need to be an equal amount or could more of these sterile neutrinos be anti-left than right, and second if more sterile neutrinos are found to be anti-matter (anti-left neutrinos) than matter (right neutrinos), would such an experiment hypothetically show why there is matter in the universe left that didn't annihilate with antimatter shortly after the big bang?

Comment: For Dirac fermions, the number of L particles is matched by the number of R antiparticles, and the number of (sterile) R particles is matched by the number of L antiparticles.  For Majorana fermions,   particles and antiparticles are the same, so C decouples from your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

The particles we know for sure exist (left-handed neutrinos and their antiparticles), then there are NO right-handed neutrinos, so the question of their number becomes irrelevant.

However, some scientists believe there might be extra, invisible right-handed neutrinos out there. If they do exist, their number doesn't necessarily have to be the same as the number of anti-left-handed neutrinos. It could be more, less, or even impossible to count!

So, the short answer is: we don't know yet. We need to discover these mysterious right-handed neutrinos first before we can figure out how many there are compared to their anti-left-handed cousins.